# Java Servlet returning wrong data?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm working on a [JSP <-> Javascript <-> Servlet <-> Restful Api] project. I created a servlet called "CRUD" where recieves all the request from the entire web with an ID and URL, then returns a generic answer with the returned data from the API.

My problem begins when I want to make several request at the same time, the servlet return wrong data to the ajax request. For example, if I make 3 requests, customers, products and prices, customers recieves products, products recieves prices and prices recieves customers.

This only happens when I do multiple requests at the same time, if I do 1 by 1, the data it's recieved correctly.

Example:

Javascript:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({url: 'crud', type: 'GET', dataType: 'JSON', data: {
        requestID: 'customers'
     }).done(function(data) {
        //this recieves products
     });
     $.ajax({url: 'crud', type: 'GET', dataType: 'JSON', data: {
        requestID: 'products'
     }).done(function(data) {
        //this recieves prices
     });
     $.ajax({url: 'crud', type: 'GET', dataType: 'JSON', data: {
        requestID: 'prices'
     }).done(function(data) {
        //this recieves customers
     });
  });
```

CRUD Servlet:

```
HashMap<String, String> urls;

static {

  urls = new HashMap();
  urls.put("customers", "api/customer");
  urls.put("products", "api/products");
  urls.put("prices", "api/prices");

}

@WebServlet(name = "CRUD", urlPatterns = {"/CRUD"})
public class CRUD extends HttpServlet {
   JSONObject wsResponse = new JSONObject();

   /*
    Format:
    wsResponse: {
      type: 'success' -> this can be success/error
      data: {} -> this is the json object returned by the api/webservice
    }
   */

   String requestURL = (HashMap<String, String>) urls.get(request.getParameter("requestID"));// -> HashMap with the paths from the api based on an ID

   String authToken = request.getSession().getAttribute("token");

   wsResponse = getData(authToken,requestURL);


   response.getWritter().print(wsResponse);
}


public JSONObject getData(String authToken, String requestURL) {

  JSONObject wsResponse = new JSONObject();

  try {

      URL url = new URL(requestURL);
      HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
      http.setRequestMethod("GET");

      Integer response_code = http.getResponseCode();

      if (response_code == 200) {

        wsResponse.put("type", "success");
        wsResponse.put("data", new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(http.getInputStream()), "UTF-8"));

      } else {
        wsResponse.put("type", "error");
        wsResponse.put("data", "Error while recieving data");
      }


  }catch(Exception e) {
    wsResponse.put("type", "error");
    wsResponse.put("data", "Error while working on the request")
  }

  return wsResponse;

}
```

What Am I doing wrong? What can I do to solve this? Is this a "good" way to manage multiple requests?

The reason why I'm not doing the directly to the API it's to hide the URL and the AuthToken variables(not changeable, requested by my client).

I'm really lost at this problem. I would love to have some orientation.

Comment: So, in other words, the `urls` is containing wrong entries? This is not visible in the information provided so far so we can't help much.

Comment: No, the requests are being well recieved and processed in the servlet. The problem is in the javascript, when it catch the response contains a different object from the one requested.

I request customers, the servlet process the request and returns the data, but instead of recieving customers I for example recieve products. This only happens when I do MULTIPLE requests at the same time. If i do only 1 request, it does not happen

Comment: Okay. Apparently your servlet is not programmed in a thread safe way, but that can also not be answered because the information provided so far is incomplete. It's not in a [mcve] flavor at all.

Comment: @BalusC Added aditional code to the Servlet part

Comment: Perhaps, attaching requestID back to the response will help.